# Convert Year, Month and Day fields into a date to do math

Tags: javascript, acrobat

All,
I have a form with three separate text fields. Year, Month and Day.
I am trying to figure out how to combine them and make a date (date format doesn't matter) and then subtract it from another date to find the number of days between them.

The problem is...I am a newbie to JavaScript and can't find anything on the web to use as a tutorial.

If someone could get me started, I would greatly appreciate it.

My text fields are literally ("Year", "Month" and "Day"). I'm guessing that there is a way to concatenate the three numbers and then convert to a date? THe below is where I am at, and I know it is way off, so...

```
var cYar = this.getField("Year").value
var cMon = this.getField("Month").value
var cDay = this.getField("Day").value
var cSrt = concat(cYar,'-',cMon,'-',cDay)as date
var cYar2 = this.getField("lveyear").value
var cMon2 = this.getField("lvemon").value
var cDay2 = this.getField("lveday").value
var cEnd = concat(cYar2,'-',cMon2,'-',cDay2)as date

this.getField("numdays")event.value = (cEnd-Csrt)+1
```

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

The `Date` constructor supports all your data. [Refer MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date)

```
new Date(year, monthIndex[, day[, hours[, minutes[, seconds [, milliseconds]]]]])
```

- Date objects support math operations which operate using Epoch timestamp.
- Please note monthIndex starts from `January = 0`

```js
const convertToDate = (yyyy, mm, dd) => new Date(yyyy, mm - 1, dd);
convertToDate(2020, 09, 19) - convertToDate(2020, 09, 18)
```

Output: **`86400000`** (24 hours in milliseconds)

If you're trying to get number of days:

```js
const dateA = convertToDate(cYar, cMon, cDay);
const dateB = convertToDate(cYar2, cMon2, cDay2);
const numDays = parseInt((dateB - dateA) / 86400000);
```

Here's a fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/d2v8hpc1/

Comment: OK...so I se the const operator, but how do I combine the three fields to create the date it will use as a new date? Can I simply use a concat to accomplish this inside of Date()? Do I need to set the variables as Strings instead of just the field value?

Comment: no this approach doesn't deal with string manipulation.

Comment: OK...I guess I need a little more help. Sorry to be so slow, but I am an old school VB guy. This JavaScript is making me crazy! LOL

Comment: Using the code you provided, I am assuming I declare my variables, and add in your text. Place this in the On Blur action in the final day entry and once leaving that field, it should calculate and fill in the number of days field. Do I have to actually create the dates and place them in a text field or can I just use them in the code alone to do the math? How can I use the dates if not assigning them (DateA and DateB) to variables? And if I do assign, how do I do that? Can you declare a variable without the = "something"?

Comment: I found a tutorial on working with dates in Acrobat: Am here now...still not working though.
var cYar = this.getField("Year").value;
var cMon = this.getField("Month").value;
var cDay = this.getField("Day").value;
var cYar2 = this.getField("lveyear").value;
var cMon2 = this.getField("lvemon").value;
var cDay2 = this.getField("lveday").value;
var dateA = new Date(cYar, cMon, cDay);
var dateB = new Date(cYar2, cMon2, cDay2);
var diff = dateB.getTime() - dateA.getTime();
var oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
var cNumdays = diff/oneDay;
this.getField("numDays").value = cNumdays

Comment: As stated above, I am trying to run this from the On Blur action in the final day entry. After leaving the field, then populate the numdays field.

Comment: OK...your just showing off now! LOL I have it working sort of. I get a value returned but not what I was expecting... I am getting "NaN" I am sure that means something, but not to me.

Comment: sorry if it didn't help but my only intention to guide you, no show offs, haha! `NaN` is `not a number`. if your date parts aren't valid, it'll lead to "Invalid Date" object. subtracting with invalid date causes `NaN`. better to validate your values before usage. i've handled these stuff in my example, check it out. sorry can't help it, had to mention :P

Comment: Abihlash, II figured it out...wasn't as hard as my brain was trying to make it. Thanks for your guidance...best way to learn is through a "Baptism in Fire!"

Answer (score 0):

You might look for the description of the `Date` Object, which is part of the JavaScript Core.

You also should look in the Acrobat JavaScript documentation at the `util.scand()` and `util.printd()` methods.